# How can I stop brute force with IIS6 basic http authentication?

Tags: security, http-basic-authentication, brute-force-attacks

Is there a way to restrict incorrect login attempts and add some sort of timeout to stop basic auth being brute forced, using IIS?

Comment: Set account lockout policy.

Answer (score 3):

IIS6 basic authentication by default uses the local login policy, so whatever your security policy is set to on your server should apply.

Please note that basic authentication uses Base64 encoding, which is *not* encryption; credentials are sent plain text. If you house sensitive data on  your server, you should at least use SSL/TLS.